# Absolute Import Not Working, But Relative Import Does

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

Here is my app structure:

```
foodo/
    setup.py
    foodo/
        __init__.py
        foodo.py
        models.py
```

`foodo/foodo/foodo.py` imports classes from the `models.py` module:

```
from foodo.models import User
```

which throws an `ImportError`:

```
ImportError: No module named models
```

However, it does work if I use a relative import:

```
from models import User
```

And it also works if I put in an pdb breakpoint before the import and continue.

I should be able to use both absolute and relative imports right?

Comment: How are you running `foodo/foodo/foodo.py`? If you've changed directory into `foodo/foodo/` and run `python foodo.py`, you'll get the behavior you describe. Instead, cd into `foodo/` and run `python -m foodo.foodo` and everything should work as intended. (You may additionally need `from __future__ import absolute_imports`, since the package and inner module name are the same.)

Comment: Hi thanks, yes __future__ works. So my options are to use this or relative imports?

Comment: Yes, you are also correct that renaming the inner foodo module fixes the issue and I can use the absolute import. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a *local* module `foodoo` inside the `foodoo` package. Imports in Python 2 always first look for names in the current package before looking for a top-level name.

Either rename the `foodoo` module inside the `foodoo` package (eliminating the possibility that a local `foodoo` is found first) or use:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

at the top of your modules in your package to enable Python-3 style imports where the top-level modules are the only modules searched  unless you prefix the name with `.` to make a name relative.  See [PEP 328 -- *Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for more details.

Comment: Hi thanks, 

I renamed foodo/foodo/foodo.py to foodo/foodo/main.py but to no avail.

I also tested by creating a dummy directory with all unique package/module names, but also got the error

Comment: @LaSmell: are you  certain that a) you cleared all stale `.pyc` files or b) used entirely new names that you are guaranteed to not have `.pyc` files for? I can reproduce your issue exactly and fix it with using `from __future__ import absolute_imports` in *each module* in the package that needs to be able to do imports from the package.

Comment: Yes I did both (a) and (b). I'm definitely doing something wrong here . . .

The __future__ doesn't work on my test package/modules either

Just to clarify, the top level foodo dir doesn't have an __init__, the foodo package does (/foodo/foodo/__init__.py)

Comment: @LaSmell: yes, that's clear. Are you by any chance trying to run a module in the package as a script? You can't do that, as that would mean the file is 'imported' as `__main__` and has no context of a package.

Comment: no i'm not running a module in the package as a script. I'm installing the 'foodo' package via setup.py distutils (packages=['foodo']), which installs the foodo package (with all modules) to the virtual envs python site-packages dir and puts the executable 'foodo' script in the /usr/bin where the package is imported and executed.

Comment: Hi thanks, yes __future__ works, I'm just after trying there. So my options are to use this or relative imports?

Comment: @LaSmell: yes, in Python local names trump top-level names unless you use `from __future__ import absolute_imports` and in your case you can't use anything but such implicit relative imports if you used the same name as the top-level package.

Comment: Thanks Martin, you were correct with you first answer: renaming the inner foodo module solved my issue and I was able to use the absolute import. Between @Blckkngt above and yourself I found what was catching me: 1. Don't execute package modules as scripts 2. Local module names trump packages if they are the same unless you are explicit with __future__ . Thanks so much guys, I learned a lot.

Comment: Minor syntax comment: should it be`from __future__ import absolute_import` (singular import, no `s` at end)?