# Absolute imports in python not working, relative imports work

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

I can't seem to get absolute imports to work in python. Here is my file structure:

```
a/
  b/
    __init__.py
  __init__.py
  foo.py
```

foo.py:

```
# Including or removing the __future__ import has no effect
from __future__ import absolute_import
from a import b  # just `import b` works fine
print "success!"
```

I instead get:

```
ImportError: No module named a
```

What in the world is going on here? I feel like I'm missing something basic. While this example is trivial, I need absolute imports to work for the real project, so just replacing the import with a relative one is not an option. I'm using python 2.7.13

None of the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068391/absolute-import-not-working-but-relative-import-does) help

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Is `foo.py` inside the `a` directory? You're showing it as outside in your diagram.

Comment: my bad, thanks for the catch

Comment: It sounds like you're making the common mistake of running a submodule of a package directly instead of as a submodule. There's a dupe somewhere around here - tons of dupes, really, but I think there's at least one good one.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? I'm still a little confused as to what the problem is.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe what @user2357112 says is that you should be writing down `import a.b` since `b` is a submodule of `a`

Comment: No cigar, unfortunately: `ImportError: No module named a.b`

Comment: Is `a` in your `sys.path`? I have a strong feeling that the answer is "no", in which case it really is no surprise that `import a` fails.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since it's not shown, I have to assume you're running `python a/foo.py`, this puts the directory of the script (`'a'`) on the beginning of `sys.path` when in reality you want the current directory on the beginning of `sys.path`.

You should instead run `python -m a.foo` which will correctly initialize the `sys.path` roots for your project structure.

Here's [a more in-depth writeup](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/wiki/PythonPathSadness) that I wrote on other ways this same problem can go pearshaped.

Additionally I recorded a video on the topic: [don't run `python my/script.py`!](https://youtu.be/hgCVIa5qQhM)

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution/explanation I was looking for. The link is also incredibly helpful.

Comment: How do I make this changes if running a debugger on VS Code?