# python: importing functions from higher-level subpackage

Tags: python, package, python-import, pythonpath

I'm trying to import a function from a higher level directory. I believe converting my script to a python "package" is the best way to do this:

```
package/
    __init__.py  # contains add function
    subpackage/
       __init__.py
       my_script.py  # where I want to import add function
```

Let's say the function I want to import is simple:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I should be able to do something like this in `my_script.py`, per the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

```
from package import add

print(add(5, 6))
```

But I'm getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're probably running `python package/subpackage/my_script.py` -- try `python -m package.subpackage.my_script`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute imports in python not working, relative imports work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448182/absolute-imports-in-python-not-working-relative-imports-work)

Comment: Duplicate reference is not helpful. I'm still unable to get this to work...

Comment: how are you running your program?

Answer (score -1):

You should import your sub-package by referencing it from the main-package. See code below:

```
from package.subpackage import my_script

print(my_script.add(5,6))
```

Comment: `no module called package` indicates that this won't work either. There is a fundamental problem with the way OP invokes their code.