# Why does Python select this unexpected module to import

Tags: python, package, python-packaging

I am working with a project that has a user-written module called `types.py` buried in a second-level package (its path from the project root is `package/subpackage/types.py`).

This is causing problems because the Python library also has a `types` module. When `enum.py`, another Python library module, attempts to import `types`, the user-written version is imported instead, wreaking havoc.

What's puzzling me is that the import inside `enum.py` does not qualify `types` with any package names:

```
# line 10 of enum.py:
from types import MappingProxyType, DynamicClassAttribute
```

so why is Python selecting the user-written `types` which is in a two-level subpackage? It seems to me the user-written `types` would only be imported if one uses

```
# what I expect an 'import' would have to be like to access the user-written types.py
from package.subpackage.types import ...
```

Another possible explanation would be that `sys.path` contained the `package/subpackage` directory, but this is not the case when I print its content right before the `enum.py import`:

```
enum.py: Path:
/home/me/PycharmProjects/myproject
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/myproject/lib/python37.zip
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/myproject/lib/python3.7
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/myproject/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/myproject/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

So, how can the importing of the user-written `types.py` module be explained?

**UPDATE**: the first comment suggests this happens because my project's path is the first item in `sys.path`. However, I set up a really simple project in which a module called `mymodule` is in `package.subpackage`:

[image: Sandbox Project]

Importing from `mymodule` without using the package and subpackage names does not work:

```
# main.py
# Works:
from package.subpackage.mymodule import my_module_field

# Does not work:
# from mymodule import my_module_field
```

So I still do not understand why the `from types import` in `enum.py` can work find the user-written `types.py` without the packages names.

**UPDATE 2**: printing out more information, I see that when I print `sys.path` as soon as `enum.py` starts (I modified the standard library file to print it), I see that the `package/subpackage` directory **is** in `sys.path`, even though it was not at the beginning of execution. So this explains why the user-written `typos.py` is being used.

The issue now is why `sys.path` is appended with the `package/subpackage` directory. I searched all occurrences of `sys.path` in my code and even though the current directory is appended to it at some points, it is never the `package/subpackage` directory. Where can this be happening?

Comment: Because of `/home/me/PycharmProjects/myproject` being first in your path, `types` are first imported from your project, not from stdlib.

Comment: Thanks, @sanyash, that's interesting, but how does the import find the user-written types.py without package and subpackage? I've updated my question to show a test I wrote that illustrates this.

Comment: use the `__init__.py` to resolve relative import issues

Comment: @sanyash - sys.path is only used *after* Python looks in the built in modules. The built in modules can be seen using `sys.builtin_module_names`

Comment: @user118967 - Are the two __init__.py files (that are shown in the screenshot) empty?

Comment: @RHP: yes, they are completely empty. And the ones in the actual project only set __version__, otherwise also empty.

Comment: @bcr: even if I manage to resolve relative import issues using __init__, the question remains as to how and why Python is bringing in the user-written types.py even though it is inside a subpackage that is not mentioned in the import.

Comment: Without access to the actual project files, I find this question is very hard to answer. I would recommend cloning the project, removing everything you think is not causing the problem one chunk at a time and checking when the problem disappears. You haven't provided a minimal example that still has the same issue - trying to reproduce the issue in a minimal setting is the first step towards solving the mystery (and perhaps the problem).

Comment: Why not answer your own question (and perhaps edit it with hindsight to ask about the real problem) rather than editing the question to be an explanation?

Comment: I agree with @Davis-Herring that you can answer your own question and explain in details what happened and why, how to avoid that in future. So if somebody will have situation like yours - will be able find your question and solution.

Comment: Since I can't VTC a bountied question, here's a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45448394/812183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this counts as a real answer because it would not be possible to answer it based on the question information by itself (and adding all the details to the question is impractical). In any case, here's the solution.

Basically, upon greater inspection I found out that a script invokes another script as an external process, and this latter script is in the `package/subpackage` directory, which is added to `sys.path` in the new process. About this last point, I'm not sure why; I am assuming that a script's current directory is always added to `sys.path`.

Comment: It is somewhat strange because sys.path should (from my knowledge) be used only after python looks in the built in modules. Do you know that a types.py file exists elsewhere for sure (apart from the one in your package) ?

Comment: @user118967 Can you provide a minimal example that has the same issue?

Comment: Yes, the directory of a script is always added to sys.path.

Comment: @RahulP:  That is incorrect.  Python uses `sys.path` to find all modules, built-in or not.