# Local imports - No module named 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x

My file structure looks like this

```
.
├── app.py
└── tests
    ├── Test.py
    ├── Test0.py
    └── __init__.py
```

This is app.py:

```
import tests.Test
```

This is Test.py

```
import Test0
```

What is in `Test0.py` is irrelevant. Let's just say it contains nothing. `__init__.py` is also empty. 
When I run the command `python3 app.py`, I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Test0'

This is strange since if I change Test.py to:

```
from . import Test0
```

it all works perfectly; no errors.

I cannot understand why. I thought simply using `import x` would attempt to import a module named `x` either locally or from the standard lib.

Can somebody explain this behaviour to me? Additionally if there is a way to simply import just using `import Test0` please tell me.

Python sandbox replicating issue: https://repl.it/repls/FirsthandQuickBytecode

Comment: How would I reproduce this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279810/what-does-a-in-an-import-statement-in-python-mean

Comment: @nicomp I have added a link in the question description to a python sandbox which replicates the problem

Comment: Try checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448182/absolute-imports-in-python-not-working-relative-imports-work) to get a better understanding of why it doesn't find the module(s).

Comment: This relevant information can be found [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). Basically the imported module has to be on the path for absolute imports. This is not the case if it's inside a package.

Comment: @oittaa I see. After running this in python 2.7, it worked. So was it made a requirement to have relative imports be explicit since python 3??