# Python 3.8.0 always get either linting warning or ModuleNotFoundError from imports in the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, flake8, linter

I have the following setup:

```
animals
 - __init__.py
 - main.py
 - pets.py
  * class Dog
```

If I do `from pets import Dog` from main.py, I get a linter warning on the latest versions of pylint, flake8, and bandit. Intellisense recommends I do `from animals.pets import Dog` from main.py but this gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pets'`.

At this point it is really just an annoyance since I can ignore the linter warnings but I would really like to get this fixed.

EDIT:

I have tried the following things from main.py

```
from .pets import Dog
from . import pets.Dog
import pets.Dog
```

and many more. Every single one gives me either a linter warning or throws an error.

Comment: The directory `animals` is in needs to be on the pythonpath to be found.

Comment: run your code via `python -m animals.main` and not `python animals/main.py` -- the latter [does things to sys.path that you don't expect](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/wiki/PythonPathSadness)

Comment: if that's the case, this is a dupe target (I'm not 100% sure or I'd mark it myself): https://stackoverflow.com/q/45448182/812183

Comment: @AnthonySottile Thank you! This did help. I wasn't able to find that thread before for some reason. This has been a problem for a while now that I've been ignoring but I have looked it up many times. I'll mark it.