# python3 explicit relative importing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I'm staring to package my python code.
My package structure is:

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    /subpackage
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
```

In my module2, if I use absolute importing like:

```
from mypackage.subpackage import module1
```

this will work.

However, If I use explicit importing like:

```
from . import module1
```

This gives me

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

---

I've googling about this and find out that implicit relative import is not good. But my import is explicit and it gives me such an error message.
Can somebody help me understand why?
Thanks

Comment: run with `python -m mypackage.subpackage.module2` not `python mypackage/subpackage/module2.py`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448182/absolute-imports-in-python-not-working-relative-imports-work/45448394#45448394

Answer (score 0):

Relative import only works from inside a package. If you had `mypackage` as a requirement to your actual executable code (a pure library) and used explicit relative imports, it would be fine. However if you're trying to run `module2` directly, your code says

> Find the package that `__main__` is in, find its parent, and find ITS child named `module1`

This is obviously nonsense, since `__main__` has no parent (by definition)

Comment: Does this mean from which directory that I run code makes a difference? I did noticed that __main__ is None.