# File import issue - python Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a file in my management/commands folder and I am trying to import my models into the report.py folder. However, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Timmeh\source\Python\Django Projects\env\topxgym\members\management\commands\report.py", line 2, in <module>
    from members.models import ActiveMember
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'members'
```

I have a active.py file in that same folder with the same import and it works. However, the active.py is run from python manage.py active. The report.py I am just compiling/running it (not running it from python manage.py). That is the only difference.

the file structure.
[image]

Comment: And what is the Import Error messages you receive? The error is expected since running `report.py` directly sets the work dir to the directory which contains this file. To work around you'll need to change the import to a relative import. Let us know the error message exactly for further comments.

Comment: The error message is the traceback in the beginning of my post. says line 2 has a problem. from members.models import ActiveMember ---- No module named 'members' which is the folder's name which has my models.py file. That is the old error message I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

## Please don't forget to add `__init__.py` for every folder.

More here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages

## Try to made relative import.

```
from ..models import ActiveMember
```

if it works, this answer can help:
[Absolute imports in python not working, relative imports work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448182/absolute-imports-in-python-not-working-relative-imports-work)

## Try to check your project settings.

Have you add yors `members` app in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` list?

Comment: Hi Maxim, I thought in python3 it's no longer required? However, if you look at the picture every level has a __init__.py management/commands both have __init__.py files. and members is created by django it's and app so it has that file automatically.

Comment: sorry, you are right. My IDE shows me non-module folder and if import is not possible. A add info in Answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty hack which should solve the issue.

and I'll also point out an alternate one if that suits your use case.

#### First Option

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(r'c:\Users\Timmeh\source\Python\Django Projects\env\topxgym')

# now your import should work
from members.models import ActiveMember
```

This is dirty because it manipulates sys path which is not a good practice. I'm assuming this script is just a standalone script you wish to run, hence it should not be an issue overall.

#### Second Option

IFF this is a possibility, you could just move your `report.py` and keep it inside `topxgym` folder (at the same level as `requirements.txt`)

In that case too, the same import statement would work.

#### side note

If you're looking to access the ORM from a standalone script, it looks like you might be missing to add the django configuration in the script as recommended by the documentation.

After your import issues are fixed by either of the above two methods, if it works, great. If it doesn't it would mean that you have to add the `django.setup()` config and specify a settings file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, the problem was solved when I installed django Globally not inside my venv.